# Is there a way to get only the date time part from a zoned date time

Tags: java, datetime, time, java-time

I have code that gets the current time with time zone. Is there any way to get the date time part without using string truncations?
I'm pretty sure if I'm missing some time library method that can do it.

Currently, I have

```
ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
```

This gives output similar to

```
2023-11-19T10:20:30.123+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
```

What I'd want is

```
2023-11-19T10:20:30.123Z
```

Comment: Why do you want `Z` at the end?  It means `Zulu`, indicating the time is in UTC. Assuming `2023-11-19T10:20:30.123+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]` is correct, transforming it to `2023-11-19T10:20:30.123Z` is incorrect.

Comment: The _Z_ would represent _[zulu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Time_zones)_, meaning _UTC±0_.  Would this be correct for your timestamp?  You're currently using an offset of  _UTC+05:30_.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can simply use [`ZonedDateTime#toLocalDateTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toLocalDateTime()) to get `LocalDateTime`:

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"))
        .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
LocalDateTime localDateTime = zonedDateTime.toLocalDateTime(); 
// example output: 2023-11-20T20:22:33.003
```

### Edit

Base on your comment:

> I had missed a Z in my output. This doesn't give the Z at the end

The output format include `Z` at the end, indicating the time is in the **UTC** time zone, in this case, you can use `OffsetDateTime` instead of `LocalDateTime` like this:

```
OffsetDateTime utcDateTime = zonedDateTime.toOffsetDateTime()
        .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
// output: 2023-11-20T14:56:23.734Z
```

Comment: I had missed a Z in my output. This doesn't give the Z at the end

Comment: @rohitt Ok, I edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Call `ZonedDateTime#toInstant`, then `Instant#toString`.

Or skip the `ZonedDateTime`:

```
Instant
    .now()  // Capture the current moment as seen in UTC. 
    .truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MILLIS )  // Drop any micros & nanos. 
    .toString()  // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

Code [runs at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/QuJzB4).

> 2023-11-20T21:49:55.598Z

## Details

Your prose does not match your example data.

### `LocalDateTime`

Your prose asks for date and time without the time zone and offset. For that, call `ZonedDateTime#toLocalDateTime`. See correct [Answer by LAIDANI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77516811/642706).

Caution: Discarding the zone and offset is likely unwise, and often indicates a programmer who does not understand proper date-time handling.

```
LocalDateTime myLocalDateTime = myZonedDateTime.toLocalDateTime() ;  // Caution: Likely unwise.
```

### `Instant`

Your example data `2023-11-19T10:20:30.123Z` has a `Z` on the end. That `Z` is an abbreviation of `+00:00`, an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from the temporal meridian of UTC. Pronounce the `Z` as “Zulu”.

The `Instant` class represents a moment as seen in UTC (an offset of zero). You can easily convert from `ZonedDateTime` to `Instant`. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall clock/calendar.

```
Instant myInstant = myZonedDateTime.toInstant() ;
```

To generate text in your desired standard ISO 8601 format, call `Instant#toString`.

```
String output = myInstant.toString() ;
```

If this output were your only goal, you could skip the `ZonedDateTime`.

```
String output = Instant.now().toString() ;
```

If you want to drop any microseconds and nanoseconds, truncate to milliseconds as seen in the Question.

```
String output = Instant.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MILLIS ).toString() ;
```